# Expand cracklib-check's dictionary

Tags: cracklib

I've started using `cracklib-check` to ensure users' passwords are suitably strong, rather than relying on my own algorithms.

However, since my project is Pokémon-themed, I get a lot of passwords like "pokemon", "pikachu123", etc.

Is it possible to expand `cracklib-check`'s dictionary to include these and other thematic words and names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shame on me for failing to use the Google correctly...

[Source](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/cracklib.html)

Create a word list file (one word per line), save it to `/usr/share/dict/`, and use the `create-cracklib-dict` command to install it. Done.